# In UWP, is there a way to make columns wrap beneath eachother?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, grid

In my UWP project, i have a page containing a grid with 4 columns that is resonably wide. 
When the screen gets smaller (less wide), the columns get cut off (unreachable as they are out of view)

Is there a possible way to make the columns wrap (preferably the third and fourth column at the same time) to have the third and fourth columns beneath the first and second?

I'd like a hardcoded values-less approach the best.

Note: i do not have to keep using the Grid, if there is an obviously better approach to this with i.e. a RelativeView i'd be in for that as well

Comment: Why don't you use `GridView`?

Comment: How about using `AdaptiveTrigger` to make the layout responsive?

Comment: @VijayNirmal I have no clue, as i am not that experienced with the whole XAML type of building views. I'll go check into GridView

Comment: @JustinXL as far is i could find with searching online, the AdaptiveTrigger only kicks in at a specified MinWidth, which i am trying to avoid. The app will be running on different machines (RPi's, PC's and tablets) which do all have different screensizes but also scalings. I'd like to make it as responsive as it can be with grabbing hold as little as possible hardcoded values.

Comment: Remember, the hardcoded values here we are talking about are effective pixels. Although the screen sizes are different, the EPXs are not that far off. Also, you should be able to work out the Window Size when the app first loads and then maybe use values like "Window Size / 4" as min in the triggers.

Comment: @JustinXL Thanks for the info! I'll give it a try.

Comment: @MaartenHeebink Do you have only one row?

Comment: @VijayNirmal No, i do not. There are multiple rows.

Comment: @MaartenHeebink Do you have a different template for each Cell?

Comment: @VijayNirmal No, the templates all have just plain text in them, with 1 cell having two buttons

Comment: @JustinXL Thanks for your info but I find my way is mucky.

Comment: @lindexi looks like the OP needs an `AdaptiveGridView` here. Which is what your answer has provided. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may use the `AdaptiveTrigger` to change it when the width be changed.

And change the Grid to WrapGrid or do some thing to make Grid show best.

[image]

To know when should use the narrow UI , you should add some code just like this:

```
<VisualState.StateTriggers>
     <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="The min size" />
</VisualState.StateTriggers>
```

When the windows size more that the min size , it will run the VisualState.

The code is below:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup>
        <VisualState x:Name="wideView">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>

            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="narrowView">
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="Grid1.(Grid.RowSpan)" Value="1"></Setter>
                <Setter Target="Grid1.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="2"></Setter>

                <Setter Target="Grid2.(Grid.RowSpan)" Value="1"></Setter>
                <Setter Target="Grid2.(Grid.Row)" Value="1"></Setter>
                <Setter Target="Grid2.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="2"></Setter>
                <Setter Target="Grid2.(Grid.Column)" Value="0"></Setter>
            </VisualState.Setters>
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="177*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="143*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="Grid1" Margin="10,10,10,10" Background="Black" Grid.RowSpan="2" ></Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="Grid2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="10,10,10,10" Background="Black" ></Grid>
</Grid>
```

Another way is use `SizeChange` that you should give the Grid a name and I want name the Grid to `Grid`.

```
 <Grid >
    <Grid x:Name="Grid">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Margin="10,10,10,10" Width="100" Height="100" Background="Black" Grid.RowSpan="2" ></Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"  Margin="10,10,10,10" Width="100" Height="100" Background="Black" ></Grid>
    </Grid>
    <GridView x:Name="GridView" Visibility="Collapsed">

    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

And I add `SizeChange` in Initialize.

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    SizeChanged += MainPage_SizeChanged;
}
```

And I will add a property which set the min width.

When the windows in the min width that can change the Grid1 and Grid2's `Grid.Row` property.

```
    private void MainPage_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewSize.Width < MinWidht)
    {
        if (_grid)
        {
            _grid = false;

            Grid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            var children = Grid.Children.ToList();
            Grid.Children.Clear();

            GridView.ItemsSource = children.ToList();
            GridView.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            Grid.Children.Clear();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (!_grid)
        {
            // change to GridView to Grid
        }
    }
}

private const double MinWidht = 700;

private bool _grid = true;
```

[image]

See: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/adaptive-grid-view-control-in-uwp-with-xaml-and-c-sharp/

Comment: Thanks for your share, but is there a way without setting the VIsualStateManager up checking on MinimalWindowWidth?
I'd like to wrap the items when they will shrink/fall off screen instead of monitoring on MinWindowWidth

Comment: I have another way, I will add it.

Comment: @MaartenHeebink I add to change Grid to GridView.